# $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x], f(x) = y^2, f(y) = z^2, f(z)=x^2 \implies x=y=z$?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Given that $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x], f(x) = y^2, f(y) = z^2, f(z)=x^2$ for some real numbers $(x,y,z)$, does it follow that $x=y=z$?

It is well known that if $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $f(x)=y, f(y)=z, f(z)=x$ then we must have $x=y=z$. This is because we can iterate the lemma $x-y|f(x)-f(y)$. However, in this similar question, the approach seems to break down (instead, we get something like $1|(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$ at the end and nothing happens.

Comment: Why can't you have $x=-y=z$?  or any order of them being negative?

Comment: I would have to point out that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @LinusS. We may only have $|x| = |y| = |z|$.

Comment: @NimaBavari do you have a proof for this? And would the absolute values disappear if we were to replace $x^2$, with, say, $x^2 + x$ or something?
Thanks!

Comment: @LinusS. You're welcome. No, I can't. I said "may, only", which means, at most. If you had replaced $x^2$s with $x^2 + x$s, then there would be more variations and the result would be far looser.